# How to wrap a PHPBB3 forum post content around Google Adsense Ad?

Tags: phpbb3

I am injecting this code

```
<!-- IF postrow.S_FIRST_ROW -->
<div style="float: left;">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--'
google_ad_client = "pub-X";
google_ad_slot = "X";
google_ad_width = 200;
google_ad_height = 200;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div><!-- ENDIF -->
```

in viewtopic_body.html just before,

`<div   class="content">{postrow.MESSAGE}</div>`

However, the post content wraps on the right side of the Google Ad but not below the Ad. I have tried many variations of float but the bottom part of the Ad is always blank.

I want to know how this wrapping issue can be fixed WITHOUT touching any other file in the PHPBB3 forum software except viewtopic_body.html. (PHBB3 Ver. 3.0.7-PL1)

*You can the see the described problem at http://www.aawartan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2*

Answer (score 0):

for the first ad for the ins use

```
display: block; border: medium none; height: 200px; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 200px;
```

for the second ad use for the ins tag..

```
style="display: block; float: left; clear: left; border: medium none; height: 200px; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 200px;"
```

Example: http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/6889/screenshot1bu.jpg

Comment: There is no change after using your ins code. The space below the ads is still white and the text does not fully wrap around it. Have a look here. http://aawartan.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=10